# The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a new Product, and add it to my database using ADO.NET Entity Framework. The product has a foreign key to a Seller. I make the link by retrieving the right Seller from the database, and do the `p.Seller = seller;`

However, I keep getting an error:

> EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null

when I execute the `db.AddToProduct(p);` line. There are similar posts on stackoverflow with this problem, but the solutions does not work.

```
    using (CastleDatabaseEntities db = new CastleDatabaseEntities())
    {
        SellerRepository sp = new SellerRepository();
        Seller seller = sp.GetSeller(username);

        Product p = new Product() { Name = name, 
            Amount = amount, 
            AmountSold = 0, 
            Price = price, 
            MaxSale = maxSales, 
            Description = description,
            Image = "",
            Suspended = false};

        p.Seller = seller;

        db.AddToProduct(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is one you normally get if p.Seller has been loaded for that entity, which wouldn't make sense since you are creating a new record.  The easy workaround is to do:

```
p.SellerKey = seller.SellerKey;
```

I know since you already have the record, it is a pain just to query a record to get the key, but it would be a good workaround to the problem.  Also, you could try doing:

```
seller.Products.Add(p);
```

See if adding the reverse relationship works.

Comment: Maybe something in the model in EF is messed up for this guy.  If you check the model, or possibly delete the entity and re-add it, it may begin to work again....